# Change input value to jquery object

Tags: jquery, string, object

When the user selects from a drop down box, I want to change the value of an input field to a jquery object, which is a span element from another page. This is working fine when I append to #myDiv; the span element shows up. However, I am trying to change a text input value, and this shows "Object object" on select change. I don't understand this inconsistency. How can I get the value to change correctly, as #myDiv does? Thank you.

```
<script>

function schedule(selectedValue){

var selectedValue = selectedValue - 1;

$.get('/file.xml', function(data)
{
    var $slides = $(data).find('span.desctext'),
    selectedslide = $slides.eq(selectedValue);

    $('#myDiv').append(selectedslide);
    $("#fvdescription").val(selectedslide);

});

}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="preview.php" method="post">
Action: <select name="whichslide" onchange="schedule(this.value)">
<option value="ab">Add & Bump</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option></select><br />
Year: <input type="text" name="year" size="3"> <br> URL: <input type="text" name="url" size="35"> <br> Description: <input type="text" name="description" id="fvdescription" size="75" value="Description goes here">  <br>
<input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here selectedslide  is a **jQuery Object**

$('#myDiv').append(selectedslide);

In this case you are appending the object to the div element

```
$("#fvdescription").val(selectedslide);
```

But here you are writing the value directly to a text field which shows as object in your textfield.

try this instead

```
$("#fvdescription").val(selectedslide.html());
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. noting is showing with the .html method; I try alert box with alert(selectedslide.html()), and yet nothing shows.

Comment: What is $slides here... Did you try logging it in console

Comment: $slides refers to six span elements on file.xml

Comment: i figured it out:     var year = selectedyear.text();
 $("#fvyear").val(year);

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't put an element as the *value* of a textbox.  It's basically just putting the `toString` value of your jQuery object as the value, which will always be "Object object" if it returns a result set.

What exactly are you wanting to display in your textbox?  If you want to text from inside the `span`, do this:

`$("#fvdescription").val(selectedslide.html());`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this way isn't working for me either... nothing is changed in the input box. I added my HTML to original post.